# How to make dice (uniform) distribution using coin toss?

Tags: algorithm, random, probability, dice

I can use only `randint(0,1)`, it's tossing coin (50% head, tail).

Using above, how can I make dice distribution (1 to 6 uniform distribution)?

I just think that if I toss many times enough, and sum all results, then `%6`, it will be uniform dice distribution, but is there a smarter method (it takes long for above)?

Comment: Well, adding up random numbers makes them more nearly Gaussian, which isn't uniform, so that won't work. How about using 0/1 values to set bits in an integer? That works just right to get a number on the range 0 to 2^m - 1 where m is the number of bits. To get other ranges, try rejection sampling -- first generate 0 to 2^m, then just try again if the number is outside the range you want.

Comment: @RobertDodier FYI I've converted your comment to a CW answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following (implemented in Python):

```py
from random import randint

def toss():
    while True:
        t =sum([2**i * randint(0,1) for i in range(3)])
        if t < 7 and t > 0:
           return t
       
        
rolls = [0] * 7
N = 1000000
for i in range(N):
    t = toss()
    rolls[t] += 1
    
print(rolls[1:])
```

Comment: It seems like there are a couple of problems with this response. One is that it's incorrect; the distribution isn't uniform. The other is that just providing code to someone who is asking a basic question isn't helpful to them except in a limited sense.

Comment: @RobertDodier Thought of a solution and implemented it wrong. It's now corrected. Thanks for pointing this out. The rest is arguable :-)

Answer (score 0):

Adding up random numbers makes them more nearly Gaussian, which isn't uniform, so that won't work.

How about using 0/1 values to set bits in an integer? That works just right to get a number on the range 0 to 2<sup>*m*</sup>−1 where *m* is the number of bits.

To get other ranges, try rejection sampling – first generate 0 to 2<sup>*m*</sup>, then just try again if the number is outside the range you want.

---

<sub>This was originally a comment by [Robert Dodier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871096/robert-dodier).</sub>